# [SOLVED} How to pose Root Bone from Blender 2.8 to UE4

Tags: animation, unreal-engine

SOLUTION:
https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/animation/1823331-how-to-pose-root-bone-from-blender-2-8-to-ue4

**Given**
As you can see in the image, I believe I correctly named my objects - namely, 'root'.
When I export the armature from Blender 2.8 to UE4, the bone hierarchy in the skeleton looks fine too. It matches the default UE4 mannequin as far as the root, pelvis bones, etc.

**Issue**
As you can see in the .gif, the *root* bone does not move with the rest of the skeleton. I've been stuck on this for quite some time now. Would really appreciate help

(Not mixamo skeleton)

[image: Blender Armature Hierarchy]

[image: UE4 Skeleton Hierarchy]

[image: Blender Export Config]

[image: Root Bone Issue]